# How can I make PCManFM-Qt File Manager Open Files with a Double Click?

Tags: lubuntu, qt

I'm running Lubuntu 20.10 with PCManFM-Qt 0.15.0.  I have configured this file manager to open files with a double click.
*Edit > Preferences > Behavior > Browsing > Open files with single click (not checked)*
But it opens files on single click. In fact, it behaves as though it were configured to open files with a single click including a delay of auto-selection.
I checked and it is not a bug. The package team cannot reproduce it. They did say that it is the default setting. If it is a problem with my installation, how can I diagnose it?

Comment: Are you logged into the Lubuntu or Openbox session?  (*I have your bug open on my display at this moment and was wondering if that was your issue*)   Also I'd suggest using `ubuntu-bug pcmanfm-qt` next time you submit a bug report..  It provides us with more information :)  Thanks for trying to make Lubuntu better

Comment: I do not have a 20.10 to hand, but I do have 21.04 and 20.04. In your Preferences > LXQt Settings > Mouse section, there's one more place to change it. It has a "Single click to activate items" option in there, besides the PCManFM-Qt settings.

Comment: @KGIII, Thank you, can you please write it up as a solution.

Comment: Glad it got you sorted. I was pretty sure that the same in all three versions. I am not sure why the package team didn't catch it when you checked with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one more rather hidden place to change that. As near as I can tell, you have to have both settings configured if you want to open files with a double click.

Open  your menu, click on Preferences, click on LXQt settings, and then click on Keyboard and Mouse. Once that opens, make sure you're in the mouse section and untick "Single click to activate items".

For reference, it should look similar to this:

[image]